# JAXB.marshal時の階層について

Tags: java, xml

こんにちは。
現在以下のようなソースコードでxmlを生成しています。

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Kusa kusa = new Kusa();
        kusa.setKusa("草");
        Kusa2 kusa2 = new Kusa2();
        kusa2.setKusa2("草2");
        kusa.setKusa2(kusa2);
        Kusa3 kusa3 = new Kusa3();
        kusa3.setKusa3("草３");
        kusa.setKusa3(kusa3);
        System.out.println("**************************************");
        JAXB.marshal(kusa, System.out);
        System.out.println("**************************************");
    }
}
```

```
public class Kusa {

    private String kusa;
    private Kusa2 kusa2;
    private Kusa3 kusa3;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getKusa() {
        return kusa;
    }

    public void setKusa(String kusa) {
        this.kusa = kusa;
    }

    public Kusa2 getKusa2() {
        return kusa2;
    }

    public void setKusa2(Kusa2 kusa2) {
        this.kusa2 = kusa2;
    }
    public Kusa3 getKusa3() {
        return kusa3;
    }

    public void setKusa3(Kusa3 kusa3) {
        this.kusa3 = kusa3;
    }

}
```

```
public class Kusa2 {
    private String kusa2;


    public String getKusa2() {
        return kusa2;
    }
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public void setKusa2(String kusa2) {
        this.kusa2 = kusa2;
    }

}
```

```
public class Kusa3 {
    private String kusa3;

    public String getKusa3() {
        return kusa3;
    }
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public void setKusa3(String kusa3) {
        this.kusa3 = kusa3;
    }
}
```

このソースにより生成されるxmlが

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kusa>
    <kusa>草</kusa>
    <kusa2>
        <kusa2>草2</kusa2>
    </kusa2>
    <kusa3>
        <kusa3>草３</kusa3>
    </kusa3>
</kusa>
```

になるのですが、やりたいこととして、kusa2・kusa3のクラスを分けた状態で、

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<kusa>
    <kusa>草</kusa>
    <kusa2>
        <kusa2>草2</kusa2>
        <kusa3>草３</kusa3>
    </kusa2>
</kusa>
```

の様にxmlを出力したいです。

勉強を始めて間もない為、見当違いなことを言っているかもしれませんが、ご教授のほど宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

`kusa2`と`kusa3`をelementに持つクラスを新しく定義してやればよいかと考えます。
下記では `Kusa2Parent` というクラスを定義しています。

```java
class Kusa {

    private String kusa;
    private Kusa2Parent kusa2 = new Kusa2Parent();

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    public String getKusa() {
        return kusa;
    }

    public void setKusa(String kusa) {
        this.kusa = kusa;
    }

    @XmlElement(nillable = true, name = "kusa2")
    public Kusa2Parent getKusa2() {
        return kusa2;
    }

    public void setKusa2(Kusa2 kusa2) {
        this.kusa2.setKusa2(kusa2);
    }

    public void setKusa3(Kusa3 kusa3) {
        this.kusa2.setKusa3(kusa3);
    }
}

class Kusa2Parent {
    private Kusa2 kusa2;
    private Kusa3 kusa3;

    @XmlElement
    public String getKusa2() {
        return kusa2.getKusa2();
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getKusa3() {
        return kusa3.getKusa3();
    }

    public void setKusa2(Kusa2 kusa2) {
        this.kusa2 = kusa2;
    }

    public void setKusa3(Kusa3 kusa3) {
        this.kusa3 = kusa3;
    }
}
```

[コード差分](https://github.com/yukihane/stackoverflow-qa/compare/01eca65..1f249e9)